# How to insert text on post link Wordpress?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

only post link current: http://mydomain/post-name
I want change only post link :  http://mydomain/blog/post-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the permalink page (Settings > Permalinks), select the last option to enter a custom permalink structure and enter this :

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

It will prepend all your post urls with `/blog/`.

**UPDATE**

To prefix posts only, use the following function in your `functions.php` :

```
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'blog/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=post&name='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');

function change_blog_links($post_link, $id=0)
{
    $post = get_post($id);
    if( is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'post'){
        return home_url('/blog/'. $post->post_name.'/');
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'change_blog_links', 1, 3);
```

Comment: You want all the pages to be prefixed or just a specific one?

Comment: No just post. all post need text /blog/ before it. (Page not need it)

Comment: Thanks. I have changed permalinks default, then change /blog/%postname%/ working

Comment: All right, just updated the answer in case of you want to manage it in an other way.